# JPanel size wont update after setting JFrame size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I'm having a bit of difficulty getting this to work.
I am creating a JFrame and adding a JPanel to it's center using BorderLayout.CENTER. Everything works phenomenally as far as creating it, but whenever I now resize the window by doing: `window.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));`, the JPanel inside doesn't automatically update to stretch to the window. I am trying to get information from the JPanel's size, but since the JPanel's size is not updating as soon as the window changes, the JPanel's size remains the same.

Here is my code (and what I'm talking about): (updateMinHeightAndWidth() and getMinHeightAndWidth() are virtually the same, but needed to be separate)

(listenLabel)

```
public class listenPanel extends JPanel {

    public void redoWindowSetup() {
        window.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        window.repaint(); //Where image is shown
        JPanel tempJPanel;
        listenButton listenButton;
        for (temporaryIncrimentVariable = 0; temporaryIncrimentVariable < list.getRows() * list.getColumns(); temporaryIncrimentVariable++) {
            tempJPanel = new JPanel();
            tempJPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            tempJPanel.setOpaque(false);
            listenButton = new listenButton();
            tempJPanel.add(listenButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            listenLabel timerLabel = new listenLabel();
            tempJPanel.add(timerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            centerPanel.add(tempJPanel);
        }
        window.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        int[] updatedMinHeightAndWidth = updateMinHeightAndWidth();
        window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(updatedMinHeightAndWidth[1], updatedMinHeightAndWidth[0]));
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.repaint();
    }

    private int[] updateMinHeightAndWidth() {
        int tempVerticalSize;
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        int upperBound = 40000;
        int lowerBound = 0;
        try {
            window.setSize(new Dimension(40, (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        while (centerPanel.getSize().height != (MAX_HEIGHT * list.getRows()) && ((lowerBound + upperBound) / 2) != lowerBound) {
            centerPanel.repaint();
            System.out.println(centerPanel.getSize().height);
            if (centerPanel.getSize().height > (MAX_HEIGHT * list.getRows())) {
                upperBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
            } else {
                lowerBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
            }
            try {
                window.setSize(new Dimension(40, (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        tempVerticalSize = upperBound;

        upperBound = 40000;
        lowerBound = 0;
        try {
            window.setSize(new Dimension((upperBound + lowerBound) / 2, 40)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        while (centerPanel.getSize().width != (MAX_WIDTH * list.getColumns()) && ((lowerBound + upperBound) / 2) != lowerBound) {
            if (centerPanel.getSize().width > (MAX_WIDTH * list.getColumns())) {
                upperBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
            } else {
                lowerBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
            }
            try {
                window.setSize(new Dimension((upperBound + lowerBound) / 2, 40)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        return new int[]{tempVerticalSize, upperBound};
    }
}
```

And my constructor

```
public TestingCenterWindow() {
    list = new ComputerList();
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setTitle("Testing Center Computers");
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    centerPanel = new listenPanel();
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(list.getRows(), list.getColumns()));

    JPanel tempJPanel;
    listenButton listenButton;
    for (temporaryIncrimentVariable = 0; temporaryIncrimentVariable < list.getRows() * list.getColumns(); temporaryIncrimentVariable++) {
        tempJPanel = new JPanel();
        tempJPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tempJPanel.setOpaque(false);
        listenButton = new listenButton();
        tempJPanel.add(listenButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        listenLabel timerLabel = new listenLabel();
        tempJPanel.add(timerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        centerPanel.add(tempJPanel);
    }

    window.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setJMenuBar(computerMenuBar);

    int[] minHeightAndWidth = getMinHeightAndWidth();
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(minHeightAndWidth[1], minHeightAndWidth[0]));

    window.setVisible(true);
}

private int[] getMinHeightAndWidth() {
    int tempVerticalSize;
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(false);
    int upperBound = 40000;
    int lowerBound = 0;
    try {
        window.setSize(new Dimension(40, (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    while (centerPanel.getSize().height != (MAX_HEIGHT * list.getRows()) && ((lowerBound + upperBound) / 2) != lowerBound) {
        if (centerPanel.getSize().height > (MAX_HEIGHT * list.getRows())) {
            upperBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
        } else {
            lowerBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
        }
        try {
            window.setSize(new Dimension(40, (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    tempVerticalSize = upperBound;

    upperBound = 40000;
    lowerBound = 0;
    try {
        window.setSize(new Dimension((upperBound + lowerBound) / 2, 40)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    while (centerPanel.getSize().width != (MAX_WIDTH * list.getColumns()) && ((lowerBound + upperBound) / 2) != lowerBound) {
        if (centerPanel.getSize().width > (MAX_WIDTH * list.getColumns())) {
            upperBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
        } else {
            lowerBound = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2;
        }
        try {
            window.setSize(new Dimension((upperBound + lowerBound) / 2, 40)); //Set window size to halfway in the middle
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    return new int[]{tempVerticalSize, upperBound};
}
```

So whenever I try to get the minimum size when I first create my window, it works perfectly fine. When the window changes size, so does the JPanel, so it can get the JPanel's size after the window changed. Whenever I do the exact same code for my listenLabel, after redoWindowSetup() is called, the window does this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG6x3.png

[image]

The blue area is what normally did stretch, but doesn't now, so the JPanel's size remains at one single value as the window changes size. I have tried using paintAll and repaint on both the window and centerPanel, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: You've posted a heck of a lot of code, most of it completely unrelated to your problem and thus potentially distracting. If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Also, your use of `Thread.sleep(...)` within a Swing program is a dangerous thing to do, and it is quite likely that your code would be far better off without this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how to fix the problem. It was simply because I needed a JFrame.revalidate() statement after setting my window size. This manually forced the panel size to update.